# Find the area between $(y-x+2)^2=9y, \ \ x=0, \ \ y=0.$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Find the area between $$(y-x+2)^2=9y , \ \ x=0, \ \ y=0.$$ The graph is attached below.

The area between these lines is
$$A=\int_0^2 ydx$$
From $(y-x+2)^2=9y \ \ (*)$ we get $$x=y+3\sqrt{y}+2 \implies dx=(1+\frac{3}{2\sqrt{y}})dy$$ Thus,
$$A=\int_0^2 ydx=\int_0^2y(1+\frac{3}{2\sqrt{y}})dy=2+2^{3/2}$$

Question: When taking square root from both sides in $(*)$, one could also get $x=y-3\sqrt{y}+2$ which would lead to the answer $2-2^{3/2}$ (negative). Is checking both cases and choosing the one with a positive answer the right thing? Or should I take any conditions into account to restrict one?

Attached the graph:

[image]

Comment: The area is infinite, of course.

Comment: Why do you integrate until $x=2$ only? Is it a constraint?

Comment: @Damien See the graph. The region between given lines lies from $x=0$ to $x=2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Why is it infinite. Looking at the graph, it shouldn't be infinite...

Comment: @VIVID you should be choosing $x=y-3\sqrt{y}+2$ because if you choose the other one then with $0 \leq y \leq 1$ the expression for $x=y\color{red}{+}3\sqrt{y}+2$ will give values of $x$ bigger than $2$.

Comment: @AnuragA but then the area is being negative, this is why I'm hesitated.

Comment: @VIVID You have set up the integral incorrectly. It should be $$\int_0^1 x dy = \int_0^1 (y-3\sqrt{y}+2) \, dy$$

Comment: If you want to use $\int_0^2 y \, dx$, then you will have to express $y$ in terms of $x$ which is rather difficult in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that your answer, $2 + 2^{3/2} > 2 + 2^1 = 4$, yet the intended region, which I presume to actually be the set satisfying all inequalities $$0 \le x \le 2, \\ 0 \le y \le 1, \\ (y-x+2)^2 \ge 9y, $$ obviously has area less than $1$, being bounded above by the triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(0,1)$?

Let's do this the correct way.  When you solved the equation $$(y - x + 2)^2 = 9y,$$ you chose $$x = y + 3\sqrt{y} + 2.$$  But when $y = 1$, this gives $x = 6$, whereas we would expect instead $x = 0$ if we are to be on the portion of the curve bounding the region of interest.  If we choose the other root, we get $$x = y - 3\sqrt{y} + 2,$$ and now when $y = 1$, we get $x = 0$ as expected.  Now we integrate, but since this equation gives us the boundary as a function of $y$, we have to integrate with respect to $y$, not $x$:  $$A = \int_{y=0}^1 y - 3\sqrt{y} + 2 \, dy = \frac{1}{2},$$ and this is consistent with our requirement that $0 < A < 1$.